# Error handling encodings in lxml

Tags: python, character-encoding, lxml

I have a very simple task to output all texts inside anchors from web page http://subscribe.ru/catalog?rss. This is my code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from lxml import etree

import urllib2
from lxml.html import document_fromstring

data = urllib2.urlopen('http://subscribe.ru/catalog?rss')
S=data.read()

oHTML = document_fromstring(S)
loLinks = oHTML.xpath("//a")

for oLink in loLinks:
    print etree.tostring(oLink)
    sLink = oLink.xpath('string()')[0]
```

The output is the following:

```
C:\Development\Python27\python.exe "D:/Topic Modeling/Playground/delme3.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Topic Modeling/Playground/delme3.py", line 15, in <module>
<a onclick="rgNav('js_tab_auth');return false;" href="">&#247;&#200;&#207;&#196; &#206;&#193; &#211;&#193;&#202;&#212;</a>
    sLink = oLink.xpath('string()')[0]
<a onclick="rgNav('js_tab_reg');return false;" href="">&#242;&#197;&#199;&#201;&#211;&#212;&#210;&#193;&#195;&#201;&#209; </a>
IndexError: string index out of range
<a class="forgot_pass" href="/member/totalrecall">&#250;&#193;&#194;&#217;&#204;&#201; &#208;&#193;&#210;&#207;&#204;&#216;?</a>

<a class="button_blue_2" id="js_loginFormBut" href="#">&#247;&#207;&#202;&#212;&#201;</a>

<a class="font_gray link_txd" href="/faq/vereinbarung.html">&#213;&#211;&#204;&#207;&#215;&#201;&#209; &#208;&#207;&#204;&#216;&#218;&#207;&#215;&#193;&#206;&#201;&#209; &#211;&#197;&#210;&#215;&#201;&#211;&#207;&#205; Subscribe.ru</a>
<a class="button_blue_2" id="js_regFormBut" href="#">&#238;&#193;&#222;&#193;&#212;&#216; &#210;&#197;&#199;&#201;&#211;&#212;&#210;&#193;&#195;&#201;&#192;</a>

<a class="rg_btn_soc rg_bs_01 js_tap_panel_selector" action="auth_email" href="#"><span><i/>Email</span></a>

<a class="rg_btn_soc rg_bs_01 js_tap_panel_selector" action="auth_openid" href="#"><span><i/>OpenID</span></a>

<a class="rg_btn_soc rg_bs_02 js_tap_panel_selector" action="auth_vkontakte" href="#"><span><i/>&#247;&#203;&#207;&#206;&#212;&#193;&#203;&#212;&#197;</span></a>

<a class="rg_btn_soc rg_bs_02 js_tap_panel_selector" action="auth_mailru" href="#"><span><i/>Mail.Ru</span></a>
 {#/if}
 {#if $P.login_register_tab == 2}

<a class="rg_btn_soc rg_bs_01 js_tap_panel_selector" action="reg_email" href="#"><span><i/>Email</span></a>

<a class="rg_btn_soc rg_bs_01 js_tap_panel_selector" action="reg_openid" href="#"><span><i/>OpenID</span></a>

<a class="rg_btn_soc rg_bs_02 js_tap_panel_selector" action="reg_vkontakte" href="#"><span><i/>&#247;&#203;&#207;&#206;&#212;&#193;&#203;&#212;&#197;</span></a>

<a class="rg_btn_soc rg_bs_02 js_tap_panel_selector" action="reg_mailru" href="#"><span><i/>Mail.Ru</span></a>
 {#/if}

<a href="" onclick="return false;">&#242;&#197;&#199;&#201;&#211;&#212;&#210;&#193;&#195;&#201;&#209;</a>
<a href="" onclick="ajax_recall_code();return false">&#247;&#217;&#211;&#204;&#193;&#212;&#216; &#197;&#221;&#197; &#210;&#193;&#218;</a>
<a href="#" class="button_blue_2" id="js_confirmFormBut">&#231;&#207;&#212;&#207;&#215;&#207;</a>

<a class="green" href="http://subs.link.subscribe.ru/422433"><strong>&#242;&#197;&#218;&#213;&#204;&#216;&#212;&#193;&#212;&#217; &#207;&#206;&#204;&#193;&#202;&#206; &#207;&#208;&#210;&#207;&#211;&#193;: "&#243;&#208;&#193;&#205; &#201;&#204;&#201; &#206;&#197; &#211;&#208;&#193;&#205;? &#247;&#207;&#212; &#215; &#222;&#197;&#205; &#215;&#207;&#208;&#210;&#207;&#211;!"</strong></a> 


<a title="Subscribe.Ru" href="/" class="logo"><dfn class="logokanal"/></a>


Process finished with exit code 1
```

So the link was extracted, but the link text could not be extracted for some reason. The output hints that there is some problem with encoding (cite contents consist only from human readible text). How could I fix this?

An attempt to decode using utf-8 also didn't work:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from lxml import etree
import urllib2
import chardet
from lxml import html

data = urllib2.urlopen('http://subscribe.ru/catalog?rss')
S=data.read()

encoding = chardet.detect(S)['encoding']
print encoding
if encoding != 'utf-8':
    S = S.decode(encoding,'replace').encode('utf-8')

oHTML = html.fromstring(S)
loLinks = oHTML.xpath("//a")

for oLink in loLinks:
    print etree.tostring(oLink)
    sLink = oLink.xpath('string()')[0]
```

It failed with the same error.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an `IndexError` (the problem is not related to encodings).

If an `<a>` element is empty (and some of them are on that web page), `oLink.xpath('string()')` in your code returns an empty list. And then `oLink.xpath('string()')[0]` gives you the `IndexError`.

The following code will give you what you want (I think). The HTML page is encoded in KOI8-R. Note that you can parse directly from the URL with lxml.

```
from lxml import html

URL = 'http://subscribe.ru/catalog?rss'

parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding="KOI8-R")
content = html.parse(URL, parser)
anchors = content.xpath("//a")

for anchor in anchors:
    text = anchor.text
    if text:  # if the anchor is not empty
        print text.encode("utf-8")
```

The output from this program starts with:

```
Вход на сайт
Регистрация 
Забыли пароль?
Войти
условия пользования сервисом Subscribe.ru
Начать регистрацию
Регистрация
Выслать еще раз
Готово
```

and ends with:

```
Спорт
Прогноз погоды
Новости и СМИ
Страны и Регионы
Общество
Дом и семья
Все разделы
ЗАО «Интернет-Проекты»
```